# Japanese かな input

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, japanese, mozc

I am using a normal Japanese keyboard on a laptop without ten keys.
I installed ubuntu, the English(US) mode, at first. And I installed the japanese lang pack afterwards. I am now switching from Romaji input to kana input mode. And I noticed that some keys behave weirdly.
In the following the first letter is the key I pressed and the second is letter appeared on my pc screen, the third the letter appeared with shift key also pressed.

```
The first row
お　おを (e.g. を = shift + お)
や　やぉ
ゆ　ゆけ
よ　よゅ
わ　わょ
ほ　ほろ
へ　ほれ (e.g. ほ appears when pressed へ)  
Yen Mark nothing

The second row
upperdoubledots　　゜「
uppercircle  む」

The third row
れ　れけ
け　やふ

The fourth row
む　ろー
ろ　nothing
```

Comment: Are you using ibus or mozc? I’ve been using Japanese ThinkPads for 10+ years and not seen this issue. What sort of notebook are you using? 

Comment: It's mozc and mine is inspiron.

Comment: Is this permanent or temporary? If so, could you  provide a complete keymap of yours? Type every key from left to right and with left shift key down, right shift key down. I know some people try to develop a new keymap for fast/comfortable-typing, perhaps related and anything match with this one, perhaps wrong wired.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I think it is a <a href="https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Replacement-Japanese-Keyboard-Inspiron-11-%E2%80%93-3000-3147-3148/dp/B01N5MJI8B">normal one</a>. It seems like a permanent issue with my かなinput, it persists after reboots

Comment: I'd like to provide a complete set of the key mapping. Is there a convenient command to produce it?

Comment: I have had a wrong keyboard for a laptop sent from Amazon or eBay several times, you-know-where, they don't think the wiring matters, they only send something looks like it. To make a keymap, you can type all of them, if you let a program to do it, it cannot be the same. *Now* you don't have to do it, we knew what was wrong with your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop keyboards act like PS/2, they have direct accesses to the mainboard.
While you press keys as much of you want until all the keys are pressed. While a USB keyboard only sends 6 of them at one time.

[image]

See: https://superuser.com/questions/456459/computer-architecture-are-usb-keyboards-less-responsive-due-to-narrow-irq-range

Comment: Thank you sir, but what can I do to mend this problem?

Comment: You are welcome. If I were you, refund that JP keyboard and put the original back to laptop, because anything can go wrong with a broken parts. You can buy a used USB keyboard (ask your friend, he will give you one). FYI, I only have used Kana input with the first word processor 30 years ago, that machine didn't allow me Roman input. I found Kana input ridiculous while writing a high school drama script. Later 親指シフト was introduced for a professional typist, I didn't find the efficiency, either. Realforce or HHKB does a better job, stick to QWERTY the universal layout.